# How to change font in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I am typing equation in beamer that involves variable $a$. How can I make it look like below?
[image]

I am using the following:

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,aps,umbc4,9pt,colorBG,slideColor]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, braket, color, hyperref, amssymb, multimedia}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{equation}
             f(a,b) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 
        \end{equation}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can this be made look as good as the following
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one line in the preamble

```tex
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

Since LaTeX Beamer normally uses sans serif font, this command changes the font family of maths equations from sans serif to serif which now looks like
[image]